# C# Unit Testing with Accessors - Constructors don't work

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, unit-testing, accessor

I have to write Unit test to my application but I have a problem. I am using C# and .NET 4. In my tests I can't acces private properties and methods of the class, so I am using automatically generated Accessors for every class in the Unit tests but ...

My constructors  for Accessor classes don't accepts theirs arguments.
Example:

```
class SearchControl(bool isLogged, MainWindow mainWindow);
class MainWindow();
```

To create object of **SearchControl** type you need to pass mainWindow object. So if I made this with not Accessor classes I cannot acces private methods and properties and I cannot test them.

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
SearchControl serchControl = new SearchControl(false, mainWindow);
```

I have to use Accessor clasees but when I do this my code is underlined with red and Visual Studio says that arguments cannot be accepted. Why, when I am passing arguments of the same type. If I pass **MainClass** object to **SearchControl_Accessor** object again I can't acces the propeerties in **MainClass**. So the code with the accessors look like this:

```
MainWindow_Accessor mainWindow = new MainWindiow_Accessor();
SearchControl_Accessor searchControl = new SearchControl_Accessor(false, mainWindow);
```

Anyone to have an idea what is wrong and what I have to do to fix it. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Your "examples" aren't valid code, which makes it very hard to tell what's going on. (Your terminology is unclear as well - what are "accessor classes"?)

Comment: So what is it that you would like to unit test but can't?

Answer (score 5):

If you must unit test private methods, perhaps the class design is bad to start with? My (somewhat feeble I admit) understanding is that the "outer world" shouldn't care about the object's private methods - only whether it does what is written on the box right. Private methods are not part of the "contract" - their implementation, return types etc. all can change, the public API is what matters.

In what scenario could your object's public methods pass the tests while private methods failed? If that's possible, then either:

- public methods are not tested properly, or
- private methods do not matter - they don't affect the way object behaves, and therefore don't need to be tested.

Or is it not possible, but you want to test private methods in order to pin down which one causes some public method to behave unexpectedly?

If that's the case, it could indicate that:

- those public methods should be smaller (doing less stuff and thanks to that not leaving you entirely baffled as to which private method could be guilty), plus
- a good idea would be to throw specific exceptions when private methods they rely on misbehave. Then you test public methods for those exceptions.

Comment: I agree with you here. Unit testing should be black-box testing of the class: no matter how you implement it (i.e. the private members), the test asserts that it behaves as is expected. You wouldn't want to change your unit tests just because you changed _how_ you implemented it (the private members) whereas the behavior did not change. The behavior is what you want to test.

Answer (score 4):

Generally you cannot access private properties, methods and fields of an object. If you really need to access it, you can consider making them `internal` (instead of `private`). If your tests live in another assembly, check out the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute. That attribute, when applied correctly to the assembly with the code you want to test, allows your assembly with the tests to access your methods, fields and properties that you have marked `internal`.

I hope that I understood your question correctly, as you use unclear terminology (accessor classes). Please explain or ask if your want to know more.

Comment: @peter: I know how to write constructors and where I have to place the logic. They are written correct. Here I wrote them this way to show you their arguments. 

About Unit test, They are in the same Solution but in different project so the assembly is not the same. I tried to make private to internal but I still can't acces them.

So the Accessor classes make that I want, I have acces to all of the components of the class but their constructors don't accept arguments which I pass...

And sorry for my english :(

Comment: If you could explain what you mean by accessor classes, I might be able to provide more help.

Comment: @Virtlink I googled that up out of curiosity, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/35b37c29-58f8-413e-b79d-4fcf16ae95a8 starts with `When creating a unit test project VS created an accessor class to allow the unit tests to get at the private/protected members/methods of the class...` so I assume that's what he's talking about.

Comment: The accessor class is the same like the original class but is generated automatically when the tests are created. Accessor class have everything that normal class have - properties, methods, WPF control (WrapPanels, Grids, Buttons and etc.) and can access private and protected methods. Yup, @Morawski answerd :)